# Sticky navbar doesn't show (but works in inspect)

Tags: javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if(this.scrollY > 20){
            $('.navbar').addClass("sticky");
        }else{
            $('.navbar').removeClass("sticky");
        }
    })
});
```

I already check it, but seems like it still not work...

Comment: Try display: fixed; because the sticky is related with the relative parent which may be out of the viewport according to scroll.

Comment: Can you provide code of the `sticky` class?

Comment: still can't work, any other ways, maybe?

Comment: in style or index? uh.. @wateroverdose

Comment: I guess, we need to see HTML and CSS code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I tried the code a while ago and I tried to derive your code based on the **JavaScript code**, and in fact it works and here is an example :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if(this.scrollY > 20){
            $('.navbar').addClass("sticky");
        }else{
            $('.navbar').removeClass("sticky");
        }
    })
});
```

```css
body
{
  height:5000px;
}

*
{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.navbar
{
  width:100%;height:50px;
  background-color:red;
}

.sticky
{
  position:sticky;top:0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar"></div>
```

---

So, according to the data that I have, the problem may be from **the layer system**, i.e. z-index, where the javascript is running and you scrolling the navbar, but it does not appear because there are simply elements that appear above it, so to solve this problem you just add a **high z-index number**

Example :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if(this.scrollY > 20){
            $('.navbar').addClass("sticky");
        }else{
            $('.navbar').removeClass("sticky");
        }
    })
});
```

```css
body
{
  height:5000px;
}

*
{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.navbar
{
  width:100%;height:50px;
  background-color:red;
}

.sticky
{
  position:sticky;top:0;
  z-index:10 /* I put a number so that it is higher than all the numbers in the file */
}

.div-1
{
  width:50%;height:200px;
  margin-top:20px;
  background-color:black;
  position:relative;
  z-index:9
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar"></div>
<div class="div-1"></div>
```